# Prevent VSCode from pasting clipboard as image in Markdown files

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I copy from certain programs (notably Excel) into a markdown file in VSCode, the contents of the clipboard get written to a `image.png` file that sits beside the file in the file system, and the in the markdown file the following is inserted

```markdown
![Alt text](image.png)
```

If I paste that same clipboard into a VSCode window with a different file type (text, python, jsx, etc.), I get the expected text representation of the content -- a small table in this case:

```
Something   Else
1   hello
2   world
```

Is there a way to prevent VSCode from converting the clipboard to an image in markdown files and instead use a text representation of the clipboard (when possible)?

Comment: that's wack. what are the contents of the image.png file? is it actually an image? or is it just a file containing the text as text?

Comment: In the case of Excel, it's a png image of the cells that I were copied (formatting and all).  Apparently the Clipboard is more complicated than I though!

Comment: related if you feel like digging deeper: https://superuser.com/q/378278/1749748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there might be something in the command pallet, and sure enough there is a `Paste as plain text` command.